# Angular (4.x.x) Material CheckBox Component (mat-checkbox) : [checked] not working

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

How this is possible????

See this:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 check-field">
    <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                  [checked]="true"
                  formControlName="flagRimb">Rimb.
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

I've put the true value on checked and still not seeing the mat-checkbox checked when component is loaded!! incredible!!!

The only thing that can disturb the behavior is the formControl, there is it:

```
     return this._formBuilder.group({
        [...],
        flagAdd : ['',Validators.required],
        [...]
    });
```

The formControlName is there because I need to set checkbox value relative to a model.value given by http rest call, but even with a default value set to true that's not working !!

It seems from the console that the exploded material html that generate the  don't inherit checked property from  <_<.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT 1 : USED checked INSTEAD [checked]**

[image]

Comment: Just to chime in even though this has already been "solved", the first parameter you're passing in with the FormGroup: `['', Validators.required]` is the starting default value for the checkbox, so `''` will render it empty. You needed to set that to `true`.

Comment: Additionally, for proper validation of checkboxes for FormControl, you'll want to use `Validators.requiredTrue` as you're looking for a truthy value. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need to use ngModel to get this to work

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="someValue">
</mat-checkbox>
```

someValue will be true (checked) or false (unchecked)

Comment: you're a real pro sea dog programmer! It's working.
Maybe official documentation say that, but i've missed the information.
I won't ask myself why the api component documentation explain also the checked property, meh ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Alternative answer with FormControl:

1. `formControlName="flagRimb"` This name needs to match what is defined in the `formBuilder.group`
2. `true` must be passed in the parameter list for the FormControl `flagRimb`
3. Validation for checkboxes should be done with `Validators.requiredTrue` vs plain `.required`

#### Component.html

```
<div class="col-lg-1 check-field">
    <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                  [checked]="true"
                  formControlName="flagRimb">Rimb.
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

#### Component.ts

```
return this._formBuilder.group({
  [...],
  flagRimb : [true, Validators.requiredTrue],
  [...]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
[checked]="true"
```

with

`[checked]="true"` OR `checked="true"`

Comment: This will get overwritten by the Component class